# Why is my AHAH textfield losing focus on keyup?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-6, ahah

Code that is part of the form

```
  $form['search'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Search',
    '#description' => 'Search by', 
    '#ahah' => array(
      'event' => 'keyup',
      'path' => 'admin/store/products/group/autocomplete',
      'wrapper' => 'products-search-wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'none', //also available: fade, slide
      'progress' => array(
        'type' => 'throbber', //also available: bar
        'message' => 'Loading results...',
      ),
    ),  
  );

  $form['search_results'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => '<div id="products-search-wrapper"></div>',
  );
```

Callback

```
function tf_cart_admin_group_autocomplete($search = NULL)
{
  $form_state = array('storage' => NULL, 'submitted' => FALSE);
  $form_build_id = $_POST['form_build_id'];
  $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);

  $args = $form['#parameters'];
  $form_id = array_shift($args);
  $form_state['post'] = $form['#post'] = $_POST;
  $form['#programmed'] = $form['#redirect'] = FALSE;

  drupal_process_form($form_id, $form, $form_state);
  $form = drupal_rebuild_form($form_id, $form_state, $args, $form_build_id);
  $search = $form_state['post']['search'];
  print drupal_json(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => "TEST AHAH $search" ));
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I came up with a workaround, but I'm not sure it's the best solution: To the form element 'search', I added: `'#attributes' => array('onclick' => '$(".ahah-processed").ajaxComplete(function(){this.focus();});'),`

Comment: you have to do it for change event too